# Text View text not starting from top?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

How to make text view text will start from top. It is showing after some pixel .

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might change the content inset top to a negative number (I think `-10.0` will do the work).

If you use the Interface Builder then it is in the Text View Size tab of the inspector (Size Inspector)...